# Get second recordset from stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-manager

I have a stored procedure in MySQL. It has 2 select queries there. Here is part of it.

```
@query="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS...LIMIT 1, 20"
    PREPARE query FROM @query;
    EXECUTE query;  
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
    select FOUND_ROWS() as numberOfRows;
```

In sql manager for my sql I have two resultsets. One is query, other is number of its rows. I get  first `resultSet` with ez sql.

```
$getReadingsByStreet=$this->db->get_results("call `mbusGetClientsByStreet`('".$_SESSION['street']."',".$_SESSION['page'].",".$_SESSION['bild'].",".$_SESSION['korp'].",".$_SESSION['flat'].",@x);");
            if ($getReadingsByStreet)
            {
                foreach ($getReadingsByStreet as $row) 
                {
                    $_SESSION['pageAmount']=$row->numberOfRows;
                    $res.="<tr><td><a class='serialLink' href='./'>".$row->serial_num."</a></td><td>".$row->value."</td><td>".$row->street." ".$row->bild." ".$row->korp." ".$row->flat."</td></tr>";
                }
        }
```

Unfortunately I can't get `numberOfRows`. `$_SESSION` doesn't change it's value. How can I get number of rows in php? It has LIMIT, so I need SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to get it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649569/pass-mysql-output-parameter-to-php-script-ez-sql
new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is  numberOfRows.$_SESSION always 20?

### follow up

ok, now I understand your problem as it's better described in the comments :))

what you miss is **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS**

use it like that:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tab_a limit 50;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

if you omit it , it will always return 50, but if you include it than the actual count as it would be without the limit

Comment: Well it's 155 as I set in in beginning of php script.

Comment: I'm going to try to pass out parameter to php srcipt again and will create new question is something goes wrong.

Comment: why don't you take the number of rows by 
`select count(id) from table_a;`

Comment: It will return count with LIMIT and I want total number of rows without limit. Moreover it is also select and I should somehow pass it's value to php script.

Comment: see above. hope this help ;)

Comment: Dude I use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. It is in my post. The problem is that I can't pass number of rows to php script.

Comment: well , use another var and pass it in php

[link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: This will be just another procedure. I can do this, but it is not best decision.

Comment: I will have to copy the whole dynamical query again just to get one int value.